# Anime movie/series about school students that go to another world with rocky territory, they fight square monsters

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, isekai

I’m trying to find a movie or series, it was an anime or some animation if I remember right. I watched it around 2010-2016.

I remember it had school students and they transport to another world or something similar like that. There wasn’t really anything, just ground and big rocks and I remember that the place looked like it was in the sky.

There were some weird ”monsters”, they were small and their shape was like a square block, they tried to kill the students, so then the students and ”monsters” fought and the students killed them I think. I also remember the students hid from the monsters behind the big rocks.

Also if I remember right the students could go back to their own world and then again back to the ”monster” world.

This is everything I can remember, its just how I remember it in my head, so some things are probably not right. I tried looking for this for hours but couldn’t find anything.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  What made you think the place they went was in the sky?

Comment: Do you remember where you watched it? YouTube? Netflix? Crunchyroll?

Comment: I think I just watched it from a television channel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That sounds like the Mountains Sector from the French cartoon *Code Lyoko* (2003-2007, four seasons).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Lyoko):

> Jeremy Belpois, a 12-year-old prodigy attending boarding school at Kadic Academy, discovers a quantum supercomputer in an abandoned factory near his school. Upon activating it, **he discovers a virtual world called Lyoko with an artificially intelligent girl named Aelita trapped inside it.** Jeremy learns of X.A.N.A., a fully autonomous, malevolent, and highly intelligent multi-agent system, that also dwells within the Supercomputer. [...]
>
> **Jeremy works tirelessly to materialize Aelita into the real world and stop attacks caused by X.A.N.A. Jeremy is aided by his three friends** Odd Della Robbia, Ulrich Stern, and Yumi Ishiyama, **who are virtualized into Lyoko to save both worlds from the sinister virtual entity.**

The gang can indeed use the supercomputer to switch between the real world and virtual world at will. No specific episode comes to mind, but [the Bloks](https://en.codelyoko.fr/monstres/profils.cl#bloks) are met in the Mountain Sector often and hiding behind rocks is a common strategy. Example in this season 1 episode:

---

Found by memory... This basically being my favourite cartoon ever.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: That’s the right one, thank you so much!